# jasmine-node fails but only reports it in "summary"

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I am running jasmine-node and encountered something really strange. Successful tests but failures in report:

```
.........

Finished in 0.142 seconds
9 tests, 11 assertions, 2 failures, 0 skipped
```

I am using done("error") to flag a failure.

Comment: Dear community. Sometimes you don't see the obvious. done.fail(errorMessage) seems to be the proper way to fail an asynchronous test.

Answer (score 0):

Use done.fail(...) instead of done(...). done.fail(...) is the proper way to fail your asynchronous test.

So when my test succeeds:

```
done()
```

And when a callback is called which shouldn't be called:

```
done.fail("error")
```

This is how I check e.g. if a Promise.catch is called when it shouldn't, i.e. all callbacks that I can't spy on with SinonJS.